# How to fill other form input when an item from dropdown has been selected in Ruby on Rails using Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

I'm a newbie using Ruby on Rails and ActiveAdmin to develop a project:

I have two models called DirectPurchase and Product.
Table migrations look like this:

Products:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :item_code
      t.string :item_name
      t.string :item_type
      t.string :central_name
      t.string :origin
      t.string :class_type
      t.decimal :unit_cost, precision: 8, scale: 2
      t.string :liens

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Direct Purchase:

```
class CreateDirectPurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :direct_purchases do |t|
      t.string :supplier
      t.string :product
      t.integer :quantity
      t.decimal :unit_cost, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :commission_rate, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :total_unit_cost, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :misc_fees_liens, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :misc_fees_insurance, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :misc_fees_storage, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :misc_fees_penalty, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :witholding_tax, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :commission_amount, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :payable_gross, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :payable_net, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.string :reference_number

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now what I want to do is on the new Direct Purchase form:

![direct purchase form][1]

The product input field is auto-populated by the existing products that have been entered in the past.

Now when I select a certain product from the dropdown list, I want the unit_cost of the product that I selected to be automatically be filled into the unit_cost field of the direct purchase form.

How to do this? My clue is to use :onchange and :input_html by as I said I'm still a newbie and don't have a clue how to do this.

/admin/direct_purchase.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register DirectPurchase do

menu parent: "Transaction"

  permit_params :supplier, :product, :quantity, :unit_cost, :commission_rate, 
  :total_unit_cost, :misc_fees_liens, :misc_fees_insurance, :misc_fees_storage, :misc_fees_penalty,
  :witholding_tax, :commission_amount, :payable_gross, :payable_net, :reference_number

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :supplier
    column :product
    column :quantity
    column :unit_cost
    column :commission_rate
    column :total_unit_cost
    column :misc_fees_liens
    column :misc_fees_insurance
    column :misc_fees_storage
    column :misc_fees_penalty
    column :witholding_tax
    column :commission_amount
    column :payable_gross
    column :payable_net
    column :reference_number
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Direct Purchase Details" do
      f.input :supplier
      f.input :product, :as => :select, :collection => Product.all.map {|product| [product.item_name, product.unit_cost]}, :input_html => {:onchange => "SOMETHING HERE"}
      f.input :quantity
      f.input :unit_cost, :input_html => {:value => "unit_cost value from selected product"}
      f.input :commission_rate
      f.input :total_unit_cost, :input_html => { :readonly => true }
      f.input :misc_fees_liens
      f.input :misc_fees_insurance
      f.input :misc_fees_storage
      f.input :misc_fees_penalty
      f.input :witholding_tax
      f.input :commission_amount
      f.input :payable_gross
      f.input :payable_net
      f.input :reference_number
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery. Create a js file in the assets/javascript forlder:

```
$("input[name='direct_purchase[product]']").change(function() {
  $("input[name='direct_purchase[unit_cost]']").val($(this).val());
});
```

Or something similar...

Comment: Hi, I added the said code as product.js inside assets/javascript folder, but it doesn't work. Is there something missing? Do I need to add something somewhere? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: This is only a sample code... you have to write on your own. Check in the browser that the input names are appropriate for example, or the change event is fired when you change the select input...etc.